# angular language translate in typescript file

Tags: angular, jhipster, angular-translate

```
public typeArray= [
       {
          id: 'MOTHER',
          name: '{{ myApp.type.MOTHER | translate }}'     
       }];
```

How can we write to translate while defining an array in a TypeScript file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use your pipes in your components or anywhere you want by importing them. Import your translate pipe to your component, then add it to constructor

```
constructor(private yourPipe: YourPipe) {}
```

or you can create a new instance from your pipe class:

```
public yourPipe: YourPipe = new YourPipe();
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
this.yourPipe.transform(value);
```

transform function will return the transformed value by the pipe.

So in your case:

```
   public typeArray = [
       {
         id: 'MOTHER',
         name: this.yourPipe.transform(myApp.type.MOTHER)
       }
   ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import `TranslateService` from `'@ngx-translate/core'` and use its `get` method.

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {}

method() {
    this.translateService.get(myApp.type.MOTHER).subscribe((mother) => 
    {
        let typeArray= [{
            id: 'MOTHER',
            name: mother     
        }];
        ...
    });
}
```